# Send message via postfix delayed

Tags: postfix, procmail

I have a script on my server that automatically answers incoming messages. This is realized with procmail. I want to write a follow-up after e.g. 24 or 48 hours. Is there a way i can realize this - best would be with procmail and/or postfix, since i am already using it.

Comment: Without any hints about what your current code looks like, are you looking for anything more that "probably yes"?

Comment: I do not think my current code is relevant in any way. It is a standard procmail expression. What i am looking for is either a flag to postfix '-delay_for_ms XXX' or '-do_not_send_before YYY' or some kind of ' delayed pipe | ' where i can pipe my new mail into.

Comment: Have you considered using `at` for delayed execution?

Comment: No, i do not know `at`. 'man at' gives no result on my system. Can you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'echo "xxx"|mail recipient@domain.tld' | at now + 1 min
```

Suggested by  Andrzej A. Filip this works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: This is more or less what I would have suggested too, but the problem now is queue management. How do you keep track of which at jobs are going to which addresses, in case you want to cancel one?